# Problem with tcp socket write not working

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, outputstream

I'm trying to write a message created using protobuf to a client socket,
but I don't know why only the code below works.

```
   mClientSSLSocket.getOutputStream().write(intToByte(message.getSerializedSize()));
   message.writeTo(mClientSSLSocket.getOutputStream());
```

```
  public int getSerializedSize() {
    if (memoizedSerializedSize == -1) {
      memoizedSerializedSize = Protobuf.getInstance().schemaFor(this).getSerializedSize(this);
    }
    return memoizedSerializedSize;
  }
```

```
    public static byte[] intToByte(int value) {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte) (value >> 24),
            (byte) (value >> 16),
            (byte) (value >> 8),
            (byte) value };
    }
```

However:

```
mClientSSLSocket.getOutputStream().write(message.getSerializedSize()); <--- NOT WORK
mClientSSLSocket.getOutputStream().write(message.toByteArray()); <----- NOT WORK
```

What I don't understand even more is that the above code
only works on **Android <-> Android**

- **and does NOT work on Android <-> IOS.**

Well, I suspect that the reason it doesn't work on Android <-> IOS is because of the line separator...
How can I use the line separator in an object type other than a String type?

Can anyone explain the above?

```
mClientSSLSocket.getOutputStream().write(message.getSerializedSize()); <--- NOT WORK
mClientSSLSocket.getOutputStream().write(message.toByteArray()); <----- NOT WORK
```

Comment: Please define "NOT WORK" - what happens? Does it throw an exception, if so what? Does nothing get sent? Does unexpected data get sent? If so, what is expected and what is the actual? If looks like the difference is message.writeTo(stream) vs stream.Write(message.toByteArray()) - is that correct? If so, have you tried writing to a memory stream and comparing the output vs toByteArray()? It looks like everything here is binary; line endings *probably* don't apply, unless one of these APIs is quietly actually a "writer" rather than a raw stream

Comment: Btw, what language/runtime is this? There are important differences, and being explicit would help. Also also: is your receiving code handling the length prefix? If so, what does that look like? Specifically I'm wondering if CPU endianness is a factor, if you're using a "punning" approach to interpret the 4 bytes back to an integer

Comment: `mClientSSLSocket.getOutputStream().write(message.getSerializedSize())` will write a *byte*. Not a 32-bit integer. @MarcGravell

Comment: @user207421 I would *expect* that to be `stream.Write(byte)`, and then I would further expect `stream.Write(integerExpression)` to cause a compiler failure about type mismatch, requiring an explicit cast which isn't present. Hence my question about language/runtime.

Comment: @user207421 have fun with that

Comment: @matt that's part of the Google.Protobuf API, which provides both stream and byte-array serialization

Comment: It actually appears you are confounding two problems. The first problem @MarcGravell has addressed. The second part about the "line endings" seems to need more information. What is the data you are sending? How does it "work" on one platform and "fail" on another platform.

Comment: @matt I'm interpreting the line-endings thing as a speculative hunch; given this appears to be stream (not text-writer), I doubt it applies - at least unless they're accidentally treating protobuf binary as encoded text data in which case they have a whole lot more problems to unpick

Comment: @MarcGravell That's why I asked op, because they say "that the above code only works on ... " Part of the code they provided writes 4 bytes. So if they're having a problem with the text, maybe isn't how it is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

As @user207421 notes, `OutputStream.write(int)` [only writes a single byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html):

> The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

You always want to write 4 bytes, hence why this isn't working.

Comment: @matt given what we know about the code that does work: the receiver is always expecting 4 bytes (big-endian int32); writing a single byte will always cause a failure, irrespective of the prefix value being greater than or less than 8 bits (even if the first 3 bytes of the payload manages to give a value that doesn't cause EOF, we'll have missed 3 values from the payload, so: still a failure)

Comment: "the receiver is always expecting 4 bytes" That's probably a correct assumption considering, `.write(intToByte(message.getSerializedSize())` works but `.write(message.getSerializedSize())` doesn't work.